# Which attribute holds the product URL?

Tags: magento-1.8, url, url-rewrite, url-key

I have a Magento store (version 1.8.1) and I installed [an extension](https://mirasvit.com/magento-extensions/advanced-product-feeds-generator.html) to export the Google product feed. I noticed that the URLs in the generated feed are redirecting so I did some checks and found that in the Magento admin all the simple product `URL keys` are the same as the configurable products. How is that possible? Where does Magento pull the actual URL used on the front end from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The product urls (yes urlS because they can me more than one) are kept in the `core_url_rewrite` table.
if a record in that table has the field `product_id` not `null` then it belongs to the product and the `request_path` is what you are looking for.
But you can have multiple cases.

1. There is no record in the `core_url_rewrite` for a specific product id: This means that the product does not have a friendly url and it can be reached only at `catalog/product/view/id/{id_here}`.
2. You have a record for a specific product id:

   1. the `options` column is empty: You can reach the product at `/{request_path_value}`.  But there can be multiple records like this in the table. Some of them might have the `category_id` column empty. This means that the product can be reached at `/product.html`. Others have a value for `category_id`. This means the product url looks like `/category/product.html` or `/category/sub-category/product.html`. You will have to pick the one you want. all of these urls are valid.
   2. The `options` column has a value. This means that the url is actually a redirect (301 or 302) to an other page. You don't want to export these urls to any feeds. They should be there for url backwards compatibility.